# jQuery .html() removing html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am setting a variable to the full contents of a `<tbody>`, after filtering the table I want to be able to return to the original full contents of the `<tbody>`. Currently, when I try to change back to the original contents, jQuery is stripping the `<script>` `<tr>` and `<td>` elements.

JavScript

```
var contents= $("tbody").html();
//load of other functions
$("tbody").html(contents);
```

The contents looks a bit like this:

```
<script>alert("Hello");</script>
<tr>
    <td>A value</td>
    <td>Another value</td>
</tr>
```

When I attempt to revert back to this contents I get:

```
 A value
 Another value
```

Comment: So what exactly is the string result of $("tbody").html() placed at the end of your code?  Is that what your last output is showing, with some result with no HTML tags at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you're using should work, as demonstrated by the following jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GbSrV/

When running the fiddle, take a look at the JavaScript console.  You'll note that the values returned by html() are as expected.

To debug your code, check the actual DOM using your browser's dev tools.  What does the tbody look like before, during, and after the routine?

Also, what exact code are you using to check the restored tbody contents?  I assume your poking the restored value in your debugger (or equivalent) using:

```
$("tbody").html()
```

If that's not the case, let us know.

You should be able to get your original code to work right.  However, if you want you could try the following implementation alternative:

```
var contents$ = $("tbody").children().clone();
// load of other functions
$("tbody").empty().append( contents$ );
```

Comment: The alternative implementation you offered worked perfectly, thanks! I had been inspecting the DOM and everytime certain tags would be removed, whilst others would be left e.g. <a>. Thanks again for your time!